# Powerpoint vba: Delete/Hide Highlight on all text

Tags: vba, powerpoint

In PowerPoint for Office 365 there is a new functionality:
[Text highlighting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/highlight-your-text-28623777-d955-4fcf-bbc5-a50051552219).

With this new function I can highlight text in shapes but want to delete or hide this later on (for a student version of the ppt).
For Word I [found a macro which works](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/word.find.highlight):

```
Sub UnHighlight
    Dim rngTemp As Range
    Set rngTemp = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=0, End:=0)
    With rngTemp.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Highlight = True
        With .Replacement
            .ClearFormatting
            .Highlight = False
        End With
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True,
        FindText:="", _
        ReplaceWith:="", Format:=True
    End With
End sub
```

Any idea to adapt this for powerpoint?

---

Adapting [something like this from WORD](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/word.view.showhighlight) for POWERPOINT would also be helpful:

```
Sub PrintWithoutHighlight()
    With ActiveDocument
        .ActiveWindow.View.Showhighlight = False
        .PrintOut
    End With
End Sub
```

Or Hide Highlighting:

```
Sub HighlightingHide()
    ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.Showhighlight = _
        Not ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.Showhighlight
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be better off using the macro recorder to record a new macro.

Comment: I used Makro-Recoder for Powerpoint 2003. But for the actual version I don't know how to use one. Do you have an advice?

Comment: @Katharina You can't record macros in PowerPoint 2016 + anymore - what are you trying to do exactly? Your question isn't clear.

Comment: @dwirony I want to delete all highlighting "on" text in all shapes of a powerpoint file :-)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "on" - so you want to un-highlight all highlighted text in powerpoint?

Comment: Yes - un-highlight and/or hide. I just added two Makros from Word to my Question, which will perhaps better show the request.

Comment: @Katharina I'm not on office 365, but you could maybe try finding text then using a find/replace on it with the same word - that might remove the highlighting.

Comment: Unfortunately there is too many highlighted text...